# PHP Get Value Radio Button in Looping

Tags: php

I have this html radiobutton:

```
<td align="center">
    <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="ok<?php echo $get_cp_id; ?>" value="OK" name="status[<?php echo $get_cp_id; ?>]">
        <label for="ok<?php echo $get_cp_id; ?>"></label>
    </div>
</td>
<td align="center">
    <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="ng<?php echo $get_cp_id; ?>" name="status[<?php echo $get_cp_id; ?>]" id="ng" value="NG">
    <label for="ng<?php echo $get_cp_id; ?>"></label>
    </div>
</td>
```

When i process it to PHP using this function:

```
$get_status = $_POST['status'];
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($get_status); $i++)
{
     echo $value = $_POST['status'][$i];
}
```

Some of value of checkbox not index. Found error like this:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in...

Comment: Show us the HTML *after* PHP has parsed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `checkbox` instead of `radiogroup` if you want multiple to be selected. Try with -

```
name="status[]"
```

Without `<?php echo $get_cp_id; ?>` 
Then it will generate them as `status[0] = value1` `status[1] = value2` ...

And the loop will be -

```
$get_status = $_POST['status'];
foreach($get_status as $status)
{
     echo $value = $status;
}
```

For you code if the option names are starting for `1` and goes sequentially the you have to change `$i = 0` to `$i = 1` in your code.

Comment: Need to do this name="status[<?php echo $get_cp_id; ?>]", if I remove it, in radio button, when I choose one OK, but choose another, the last check will go to current check

Comment: It will work for both. And also you can use checkboxes

Comment: Agreed with your answer @b0s3

Comment: FYI, the radio button is inside loop, so it can be more radio button in row.

Comment: If I set with your code, in HTML radio button, when I check first radio button is OK, but when I check to another radio button, the first check will reset then set to current check

Comment: What is wrong with the checkboxes if you want multiple?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking index 0,1,2... in php script within for loop. If you declare array in name element with auto index as below then it will work fine.

```
<input type="radio" id="ok<?php echo $get_cp_id; ?>" value="OK" name="status[][<?php echo $get_cp_id; ?>]">

<input type="radio" id="ng<?php echo $get_cp_id; ?>" name="status[][<?php echo $get_cp_id; ?>]" id="ng" value="NG">
```